# how to access a camunda variable (containing dot in name) in user task documentation

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to show value of a variable in user task description/documentation. I am able to access simple variables using `${simpleVarName}` expression but not able to access variables containing dot in name with `${notSimple.varName}` expression. is there a way to access such process variables in usertask documentation field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to solve this by using execution object.
`${execution.getVariable("notSimple.varName")}`

Also, putting variable name in quotes did not work. expression `${"notSimple.varName"}` returns variable name itself not value.